# How to colour my scatter plot with data that I've combined?

Tags: r, colors

I have two datasets (I will eventually be working with eight) that I have combined to create a scatter plot. The issue is, now I've plotted the scatter graph, I do not know how to separate the data I've combined so the colours represent the individual datasets. This is my code...

````
#Here is what I've combined:

    t<-rbind(test202, test342)

#Here is plotting the scatter-plot 

    ```{r}
    g<-ggplot(t,aes(x=percentage,y=as.numeric(area), col = area, group = area ))+
      geom_point()+
  labs(x=expression(paste("Percentage (%)")),
       y=expression(paste("Area (m"^2,")"))
       )+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(element_blank())
g
``
````

I've tried googling this but cannot seem to find any specific code to fix this. I've attached a picture of the final product and of 't's contents.
[contents of 't'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KebYs.png) [scatter-plot of 't'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgTQF.png)

EDIT: dput(t)

```
t <- structure(list(percentage = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("30", "35", 
    "40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "65", "70", "75", "80", "85", "90", 
    "95"), class = "factor"), area = c(1.0068507612755, 1.28144642344154, 
    1.55604208560758, 1.92216963516231, 2.28829718471704, 2.65442473427176, 
    3.20361605860385, 3.75280738293594, 4.39353059465671, 5.30884946854352, 
    6.49876400459638, 7.96327420281528, 10.068507612755, 13.6382512209135, 
    1.12935650675177, 1.4004020683722, 1.67144762999262, 1.98766745188312, 
    2.34906153404369, 2.75562987647432, 3.16219821890496, 3.65911508187574, 
    4.15603194484652, 4.74329732835744, 5.37573697213844, 6.18887365699971, 
    7.22788164321134, 8.89932927320397)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Where is `t`? Data is needed in order to reproduce yur issue!

Comment: I have attached the photo if you can see that? Is this what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Could you please do this in your console: `dput(t)` and paste the output in the question?

Comment: Yes, I will do this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are just losing track of the source of the data when you `rbind` the rows together.  Since you say you have more dfs to join eventiually I will provide a `dplyr` solution.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

t <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(test202 = test202,
                           test342 = test342),
                      .id = 'source')

ggplot(t, aes(x = percentage,
              y = as.numeric(area),
              col = source,
              group = source ))+
   geom_point()+
   labs(x = expression(paste("Percentage (%)")),
        y = expression(paste("Area (m"^2,")"))
   )+
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 1)) +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. In the future when I add more data would I just continue the 'bind_rows(list())' with more tests?

Comment: Exactly, just keep adding to the list of dataframes you are merging.  BTW you can name them anyway you want (on the left side of the equation).  If this solves your problem please mark the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks so much! Much appreciated (: